# Tomato to OpenVPN Server on Ubuntu Server

Tags: openvpn, site-to-site-vpn, tomato

I use OpenVPN on Ubuntu Server as VPN Server,  and Viscosity successfully working with this client configuration:

```
xxx.no-ip.org remote udp 1194
dev tun
tls-client
ca ca.crt
cert cert.crt
key key.key
tls-auth ta.key 1
persist-tun
persist-key
persist-local-ip
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo no
nobind
pull
dhcp-option DNS 192.168.8.1
BF-CBC cipher
```

Now, I want to implement that configuration in my Linksys E2500 flash with Tomato (v 1.28 shibby)
This configuration of what I have done;

'**VPN Tunneling > OpenVPN Client**' menu

'**Basic**' tab:

- **Start with WAN**: Check
- **Interface Type**: TUN
- **Protocol**: UDP
- **Server IP address / Port**: 1194 xxx.no-ip.org
- **Firewall**: Automatic
- **Authorization / Password Authentication**: Check
- **Username**: myusername
- **Password**: *******
- **Username Authen. Only**: Uncheck
- **Extra HMAC authorization (tls-auth)**: Outgoing (1)
- **Create NAT on tunnel**: Uncheck

'**Advanced**' tab

- **Poll interval**: 0
- **Redirect traffic**: Uncheck
- **Accept DNS configuration**: Strict
- **Encryption cipher**: BF-CBC
- **Compression**: Disabled
- **TSL Regeneration Time**: -1
- **Connection retry**: 30
- **Custom Configuration**:
  persist-tun
  persist-key
  persist-local-ip
  comp-lzo no
  nobind
  pull
  dhcp-option DNS 192.168.8.1

'**Keys**' tab

- **Static Key**: [content of ta.key file]
- **Certificate Authority**: [content of ca.cert file]
- **Client Certificate**: [content of cert.crt file]
- **Clent Key**: [content of key.key file]

and I was able to do 'Start Now' but this seems not work because I can not access any resources on the network under the VPN server which that I can do when I connect with Viscosity.

So, what I miss?

Comment: Based on my answer below, this is a NAT issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I do some changes, the issue is resolved, following a change of settings above;

'**Basic**' tab:

- **Create NAT on tunnel:** Checked

'**Advanced**' tab

- **Accept DNS configuration:** Relaxed
- **Compression:** None
- **Custom Configuration**
  persist-tun
  persist-key
  persist-local-ip
  comp-lzo no
  nobind
  pull

Answer (score 0):

A tip for people who stumble upon this, I had followed others suggestions with configurations to get it working, and I didn't "reboot" my router.   This was my failure - the reboot of the vpn server and vpn client router solved my routing problem from server network to get to client network hosts over the Tomato OpenVPN